# Enable Links in Accessibility Rotor VoiceOver on UIView

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uilabel, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `UIView` that contains a bunch of `subViews`. One of them is the `UILabel` which could contains a link or two.

I want the voiceover to read whatever I set for the view but allow the user to change rotor to `Links`. And the user can swipe up and down for different links.

I know `Links` works natively with `UIWebView` but I cannot find any documentation on it whether or not this is even possible. I am also looking into `UITextView` but that is a last resort as I have a lot of legacy code to prune if I make a switch.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't add an item to the rotor, but as of iOS8 you could add a UIAccessibilityCustomAction that will allow the user to select an 'Action' in the rotor. Then the user can swipe up to select your item, and then double tap to activate the item.

Here's how to add a UIAccessibilityCustomAction:

```
UIAccessibilityCustomAction *customAction = [[UIAccessibilityCustomAction alloc] initWithName:@"Next link" target:self selector:@selector(nextLink:)];
NSMutableArray *customActions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.accessibilityCustomActions]; 
[customActions addObject:customAction];
self.accessibilityCustomActions = customActions;
```

then you could track your links and allow the user to navigate through them in a nextLink: method.

Comment: Yes, that was the workaround I went with. Although, it would have been great if iOS can go from links to links via "Links" like webView. +1 for a solution.